# Path like menu button in horizontal

Tags: android, menu

Siyamed has create an wonderful Path like menu button for Android.
I would to have the child menu showed in horizontal instead of surrounding the parent menu, any have idea how should i start? 
[Siyamed satellite menu](https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu/)

[image: test]
[image: test]

Comment: use merge layout and attach it at the bottom of your layout for this type of menus

Answer (score 1):

To show Path-like menu in horizontal, consider to try ArcMenu library

https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu